# How do you use sstableloader to populate a Cassandra Cluster?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have set up a 3 node Cassandra Cluster on EC2 using Whirr. I also have a 4th EC2 instance which I am using to write sstables following the [example from DataStax](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading).

Once the sstables are written I am attempting to load the Cassandra Cluster however I keep getting :

```
Starting client (and waiting 30 seconds for gossip) ...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load any sstable, no live member found in the cluster
```

I have configured the seed in the sstableloader cassandra.yaml to be a node in the cluster, and opened up the ports between the seed node in the cluster, and the sstableloader instance. I am able to reach the seed node using cassandra-cli from the sstableloader instance, so I think that is all configured properly.

Is there anything else I am missing? Does sstableloader have to be run on one of the cluster nodes itself for gossip to work?

Answer (score 0):

Which ports did you open between the nodes? Port 7000 (by default) specifically is required for gossip.

Comment: 7000 and 9160 (TCP)
Which are the specified storage and rpc ports in the yaml on both instances.

Comment: My best bet then would be that it isn't using the conf file you think it is. Did you install cassandra from a package at some point and are now running from a download? The sstableloader script will look in places like /etc/cassandra and /usr/share/cassandra before it looks in the local directory. You could override this behavior by setting 'CASSANDRA_HOME'  to the directory containing the conf/ dir you want to use.

Comment: It is definitely using the proper config file. Following [this example](http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsPerfBlog/archive/2011/07/26/how-to-use-cassandrs-sstableloader.aspx) I was able to connect sstableloader to a second cassandra instance running on the same box, by setting up a loopback address. I can watch that cassandra instance's logs and see stabbleloader connect and start loading. Still unable to connect to a remote cluster though.